# Sometimes the screen is on when in lock mode

Tags: lock-screens

I have a Samsung Pocket GT-S5310L and sometimes, when the lock mode is on the screen never turns off (until I turn it off manually). This started to happen after I made a factory reset

When charging is ok but when I leave the phone and I receive a notification the screen stays ON. Stopping notifications is not an option and I couldn't figure out what the problem is.

Any idea what could be happening? If I can't find a way to solve the problem, I think I will do another factory reset (which I didn't want to do but I am running out of ideas).

Comment: Have you checked your timeout settings?

Comment: The only thing I see in Display options is to lock the phone after 15 seconds of no activity.